# How can I install Origin software

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows, wine

I need to install "Origin" software for graph plottings, analysis, etc. It is basically windows supported. But I have installed WINE, thereby installed few windows supported softwares and using it. But Origin is not able to install properly. Reason is I need to save one licence file in "C Drive", this is not going to happen. Can anyone help me??? How can I save licence file in C drive / installation???

Answer (score 1):

you can find it in the home directory under .wine a hidden directory. I mean

```
/home/your_user_name/.wine/drive_c
```

There you will have it.

you can also use command in your terminal.

```
locate drive_c
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is after installing origin software using Wine, I need to copy licence file into C drive i.e. :C/Programfiles/origin/originlab/Flexm/"here???", i'm not able to copy this license file. C drive is not allowing me to copy.. is there any alternate solution?

Comment: why whats the error ? If its not then type as sudo nautilus and then do it as admin.

Comment: it s not showing any error, I ll explain, 
I installed origin software, it asked me to copy two files into origin folder, this origin folder located in the C drive after installing. To copy two files into origin folder, C drive is not allowing... Hope it is clear to u now

Comment: do this then , sudo cp /path/of/wherefiles /path/to/destination

Comment: did not work, how can i chose destination in terminal? destination is "C drive - Program files"

Comment: Destination path  /home/your_user_name/.wine/drive_c/